# Creating a square results to rugged line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm creating a square using line renderer using this code

```
public class CreateLine : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
LineRenderer lr;
void Start()
{
    lr = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));
    lr.positionCount = 4;
    lr.startWidth = .13f;
    lr.endWidth = .13f;
    lr.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(0, -2, -1));
    lr.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(2, -2, -1));
    lr.SetPosition(2, new Vector3(2, 0, -1));
    lr.SetPosition(3, new Vector3(0, 0, -1));
    lr.loop = true;
    lr.useWorldSpace = false;
    Gradient gradient = new Gradient();
    gradient.SetKeys(
        new GradientColorKey[]
        {
            new GradientColorKey(Color.red, 1f),
        },
            new GradientAlphaKey[] { new GradientAlphaKey(1f, 0.0f)

        }
        );
    lr.colorGradient = gradient;


}
```

Output:
[image]

it works fine the line are smooth but when I reduce the Vector points to 1 using this code

```
    lr.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(0, -1, -1));
    lr.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(1, -1, -1));
    lr.SetPosition(2, new Vector3(1, 0, -1));
    lr.SetPosition(3, new Vector3(0, 0, -1));
```

the result is horrible
[image]

Is there a solution to this? I just need a small square. I tried scaling the size but this still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm the behaviour is a bit strange for small values.

If it is an option you could indeed simply scale it down. Additionally I would make the `alignment` `TransformZ` which also flatens the strcuture a lot:

```
private void Start()
{
    lr = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));
    lr.positionCount = 4;
    lr.startWidth = 0.13f;
    lr.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(0, -2, -1));
    lr.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(2, -2, -1));
    lr.SetPosition(2, new Vector3(2, 0, -1));
    lr.SetPosition(3, new Vector3(0, 0, -1));
    lr.loop = true;
    lr.useWorldSpace = false;
    var gradient = new Gradient();
    gradient.SetKeys(new[] { new GradientColorKey(Color.red, 1f), }, new[] { new GradientAlphaKey(1f, 0.0f) });
    lr.colorGradient = gradient;

    lr.alignment = LineAlignment.TransformZ;
    transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 0.5f;
}
```

[image]

For easier handling I would however suggest to rather use

```
    lr.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(-1, -1, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(-1, 1, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(2, new Vector3(1, 1, 0));
    lr.SetPosition(3, new Vector3(1, -1, 0));
```

so the frame is centered on the object

---

Or if it is an option use `useWorldSpace = true` and set the values accordingly (only works ofcourse if the frame is not supposed to move afterwards)

```
lr.useWorldSpace = true;
lr.SetPosition(0, transform.position + new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0));
lr.SetPosition(1, transform.position + new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0));
lr.SetPosition(2, transform.position + new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0));
lr.SetPosition(3, transform.position + new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0));
```